# What does arr.sort(key=lambda x: (-d[x], x)) mean?

Tags: python

```
arr=[2, 5, 2, 6, -1, 9999999, 5, 8, 8, 8]

from collections import defaultdict

def sortfreq(arr,n):
    
    d=defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for i in range(n):
        d[arr[i]]+=1
        print(d)
        
    arr.sort(key=lambda x:(-d[x],x)) #unable to understand this line
    print(arr)
    
    return arr
```

Output: `[8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 5, 5, -1, 6, 9999999]`

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you do and don't understand here? Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html?

Comment: You sort the list `arr` where the key for each element `x` is computed with `-d[x], x`.

Comment: sort the array according to its frequency

Comment: how -d[x], x. is working?

Comment: `-d[x],x` will sort the elements keeping the element with highest frequency first (-d[x] here  becomes lowest value and thus at first in the sorted list) and when there is a tie between frequencies of two different values, the second half of `-d[x],x` is used to break the tie. That is the value lowest will come first

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr.sort(key=lambda x:(-d[x],x))
```

Here `lambda x:(-d[x],x)` is a comparator, so first it will check the count of key(x) in the dictionary and `-ve` sign tells that sort in decreasing order of number of occurrence of a value ( that's why 8 is at starting of the sorted list as it occurs 3 times ).

The 2nd arg in `lambda x:(-d[x],x)` is x tells if occurrence of two elements is same then place lesser value first and that's why you're seeing 2 before 5.

So in comparison you can provide list of params, but the params will only be in effect when the previous params are equal for two values.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a weird code.

This sorts the array by decreasing frequency of the first `n` elements, and increasing value otherwise.

This part creates a counter limited to the first n values:

```
    d=defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for i in range(n):
        d[arr[i]]+=1
```

And thus

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x:(-d[x],x))
```

sort by decreasing count in the counter, then breaks the ties by sorting on increasing value.

A more compact version of the code would be:

```
arr=[2, 5, 2, 6, -1, 9999999, 5, 8, 8, 8]

def sortfreq(arr, n):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(arr[:n])
    return sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (-c[x], x))

sortfreq(arr, 5)
```

output:

```
[2, 2, -1, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9999999]
# counts among first 5 values
#2, 2,  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,       0
```

value of the counter:

```
{2: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, -1: 1}
```